# In Java Swing is it necessary to always have a Container?

Tags: swing, containers

I am new to Swing. There is a silly question that I have. It seems that every Swing code must have a container since all of JFrame, JWindow, etc are all containers. But I am not very sure if this is true. Can we have a swing page without a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Without the `Container` we can't add and arrange (set Layouts) components and containers. Take a look at - [Top-level swing containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).